# Extend an existing Angular/Typescript Interface

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, lint

[image: VS Code/Typescript don't like this]

So, I'm trying to get rid of the red squigglies in my component html here. The trouble is that TypeScript/VS Code can't see the property `unverifiedEmail` on the `errors` object, because it is not native to the AbstractControl. I am using a custom Validator, which is how the property is generated. That code is here:

custom.validators.ts

```
import { AuthService } from './../auth/auth.service'
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class CustomValidators {
  constructor (private authService: AuthService) { }

  unverifiedEmail (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
    if (this.authService.unverifiedEmails.some(email => email === control.value)) {
      return { unverifiedEmail: true }
    }
    return null
  }
}
```

My question is: how can I "extend" the Abstract control to include the possibility of this `unverifiedEmail` property, so that my IDE will leave me alone. Outside of the custom validator and this template, I do not interact with the AbstractControl interface or the `errors` property, so it's not like I have an obvious opportunity to import an extended version of AbstractControl (in the normal sense of extending an interface).

Thanks, y'all.

Comment: You can use the `hasError` method of a `FormControl` and supply the name of the validator as the parameter.

Comment: At last my weary eyes can see no red! Developers of future ages shall sing your praise, O Edric of the Comments!